# Ubuntu only detects Nvidia Graphics - Ignores Intel Internal Graphics

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu and I have ran into the following problem when attempting to use my internal graphics for X and my GPU only for CUDA. I cannot seem to detect the internal graphics in the first place! :0

```
$ lspci -v | grep "VGA" -A 12
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1e02 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 12a3
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at db000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f7 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 12a3
```

I haven't changed anything from the default installation (no switch to proprietary Nvidia drivers).

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your BIOS settings ?  Maybe there is an option to control which grapthics adapters to activate.

Comment: There is no such option sadly :(